# Adding a manually installed package/program manual into `texdoc`

Tags: installing, texlive, documentation, texdoc

I have manually installed a package/program related to LaTeX (it's `writer2latex` aka `w2l` in this case). Is there a way how to make `texdoc w2l` open the PDF documentation of this package?

Comment: Where did you install the `doc` subtree related to this package?

Comment: The program has no code to go into `texmf` tree (well, one file), so I didn't install anything yet.

Comment: If you put the manual in the local `doc` subtree and update with `mktexlsr` texdoc should be able to find it

Comment: @cgnieder Works, if you put the file in folder `<texmf-local>/doc/w2l/`. If you put it in a folder with a different name, it does not. Would you make that an answer, please? :)

Comment: You can add a file `<texmf-local>/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` in which you can define an alias. So even if the documentation resides in `<texmf-local>/doc/writer2latex` you can address it with `texdoc w2l` (or whatever you wish).

Comment: I had to work a little bit in the meantime and since @egreg now already has answered... :)

Comment: Another good candidate is the doc of `bibtool` which is not part of texlive and can conveniently be installed with `homebrew` or `linuxbrew`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you have a

```
<texmf-local>/doc/writer2latex
```

directory, where, say, `writer2latex.pdf` resides. In this case, the heuristics built in `texdoc` will open this file when

```
texdoc writer2latex
```

is issued.

If you want to call it with another name, create a file

```
<texmf-local>/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
```

where you can add the line

```
alias w2l = writer2latex
```

After this also the call `texdoc w2l` will resolve into opening `writer2latex.pdf`

Comment: Well, I went for calling the file `w2l` directly, since that's the name of the executable of the program, anyways.

Comment: @tohecz Alias addressing still applies: you might want that `texdoc writer2latex` opens the right file too.